# PHP read text file encoding issue

Tags: php, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file its name is `irfan.txt`. The file has following contents
`しゃ 堥珥ぎゅ駺か 監槣 橎シ`. I am using following PHP code to read file contents and save in MySQL database.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('my_db_name',$con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

$text = file_get_contents("irfan.txt");
mysql_query('UPDATE arc_text_data SET text = "'.$text.'" WHERE text_id = 29');
echo $text;

// the output of above echo is しゃ 堥珥ぎゅ駺か 監槣 橎シ
```

**Problem**

Above UPDATE query update that record with empty string. But browser shows correct text as shown in above echo statements.

I have tried all variations of solutions found on google and PHP manual site but none of them worked for me. Like `mb_convert_encoding` etc.

I have also tried `fopen` and `cURL` but same result.

**Update:**

below works perfectly

```
mysql_query('UPDATE arc_text_data SET text = "しゃ 堥珥ぎゅ駺か 監槣 橎シ" WHERE text_id = 29');
```

Thanx in advance.

**Update:**

this is my text file [irfan.txt](http://www.redsignal.biz/clients/demo/irfan.txt)

Comment: If the `echo` is working - it sounds like you're reading in the data from the text file just fine ... check the data type and collation of `arc_text_data.text` in the database.

Comment: Yes DB, table and column all have utf8 collation. As I said in comment below, direct applying text to update query works fine. Means there is no issue on db level.

Comment: Hmmm odd - check the encoding on the text file itself maybe (granted I'm clutching at straws a little). I've just cobbled up a table on mysql.test on my dev box to hold a table called `arc_text_data` (with `text_id` INT(10) unsigned and `text` TEXT collation utf8-general-ci)  and copied your exact code into a PHP file (changed the DB connection strings of course) and created a text file called `irfan.txt` with your string of data in it ... and it worked, I've got 'しゃ 堥珥ぎゅ駺か 監槣 橎シ' in the database.

Comment: @CD001 thanx for your support, I have updated my question and placed link of my text file. Can you please check code again with this file?

Comment: Ahh - looks like it is the text file. Opened it in Notepad++ and it tells me it's encoded in "UCS-2 Little Endian" - attempting to run the script with the file in that encoding fails to update the database record (or rather it succeeds but doesn't recognise the characters so you end up with an empty string). Converted the file to "UTF-8" and ran the script again and it imported fine ;)